# Jquery .ajax not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code to call a json web service in a separate functions.js file.

```
function getMajorGroups(){

var element = $(".item-group-button");

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"localhost:6458/posApplication/getAllMajorGroups",
    data:"{}",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    done:successResult(majorGroups),
    fail:errorResult(error)
});
}

function successResult(majorGroups){
    var mGroups = response.d;
    $("#item-groups").empty();

    $.each(majorGroups ,function(){
        var h3 = $('h3').append(majorGroups.code);
        element.append(h3);
        $("#item-groups").prepend(element);
    });
}

function errorResult(error){
    alert("error");
}
```

When I run the web page and I use firebug to trace the steps I can see the script is executed. But it does not execute the success or failure code inside the ajax call. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Below is an example of the string which the service return.

{"majorGroups":[{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Beverage","majorGroupId":"48","code":"Beverage"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Laundry","majorGroupId":"51","code":"Laundry"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Cigarette","majorGroupId":"50","code":"Cigarette"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Food","majorGroupId":"47","code":"Food"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Health Center","majorGroupId":"52","code":"Health Center"}],"failure":"false"}

Comment: what error does it show in console..

Comment: it doesn't show any error! when I refresh the page, it goes to through the ajax function, comes to the success function and it doesn't execute the code inside, then goes to the failure method and it doesn't execute it and exits the script!

Comment: try sending dummy data and see what happens

Comment: if your script loaded before the html, add a document ready. your request might come back before element with class item-group-button is created. Therefore success is executed, but you don't see anything.

Comment: the service returns couple of records! so it should see some data in the response! and I've already added the function call inside a document.ready function.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax` has no property named `failoure`. `error` should be used so it looks like `error: errorResult`

Besides that check that request is made via Network tab in Chrome dev tools or some similar tool. Check what is in the the raw response and make sure that is what you wanted. If request failed you will see way or at least have error code.

If everything is fine so far then make sure your adding DOM elements when DOM is ready so wrap your stuff with `$(function(){ /* your stuff here */ })`

Edit:

That's not the way `done` and `fail` should be used. jQuery ajax call returns promise.

```
$.ajax({
  url : "..."
  /* omitted */
}).done(successCallback).fail(failCallback)
```

where successCallback can be either function name like your defined succes function or just anonymous function like

```
.done(function(response){
  // do stuff with response
}
```

I think you should carefully read jQuery documentation.

Also your `$.each` call is kinda broken - you skipped parameter in function provided to `$.each`

Comment: I changed the success and failure to done and fail after going through the Jquery document. Now I get a firebug error saying that response is not defined!

Comment: Have you checked that request succeeded? Post your updated code

Comment: I added the update code! can you help me on checking the request succeed! I added the string which returns from the service call!